# How to force a function to wait until something happens?

Tags: javascript, function, angular, typescript

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <div [innerHtml]="getPostContent(post.content)" #postContentDiv></div>
  <button *ngIf="getPostContentHeight(postContentDiv)">Show more</button>
</div>
```

functions

```
getPostContent(content: any): any {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}

getPostContentHeight(postDiv: any): boolean {
  return postDiv.offsetHeight > 50;
}
```

I have a couple of posts (title, author, content, etc.) I'd like to show button `Show more` if `postContentDiv` is higher than 50px. The problem is this line:

`<button *ngIf="getPostContentHeight(postContentDiv)">Show more</button>`

is being run before this line:

`<div [innerHtml]="getPostContent(post.content)" #postContentDiv></div>`

effect? `getPostContentHeight` checks `#postContentDiv` height before it fills up by `post.content`. All works fine when I start on the component where the list is or when I refresh the page but  it doesn't work when I change to another component and go back.

### ## Example ##

In short: `getPostContentHeight` runs too fast, before another function which modifies `getPostContentHeight` argument.

Component X is a component which has the posts list and view.
Component Y is another component just for help.

start at `http://localhost:4200/X` - I see `Show more` buttons.
When I change now to component Y and then again to X, there is no `Show more` buttons. They appear after a few seconds when Angular does second check run.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to google Promises as that's what will allow you to keep a function from starting until anything that has to happen before happened (and completely).

So you'll have something like:

```html
new Promise(etPostContent(post.content)).then(getPostContentHeight(postContentDiv));
```